# How to create a drop down view text FAQ Flutter UI

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, layout

How can I create a simple drop down FAQ UI exactly or similar to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1slUo.png) that hide and unhide the text.

Edit : I have no idea what widget to use
I've read about `Visibility` but I'm not sure its the right one in this case

Comment: Hi There. Update your post with more details like what have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck ?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry I updated 
I'm stuck on the UI show hide

Comment: Hi, this seems to be incomplete code. Post full code that also contains the build function where you are currently rendering stuff.

Comment: Sorry for delay I found solution for Firebase I'll edit post now I only need the widget for hide show text now

Comment: Sure, you can update your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research I manage to find a Widget for this `ExpansionTile`
for displaying expand and collapse items
[Source](https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/Expandable-Listview-Flutter-ExpansionTile)

Alternatively there's this package [expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) which is more easier to implement

Answer (score 3):

Implemenation with `ExpansionTile` for a single question is done quickly:

```dart
class QAItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const QAItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.children,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget title;

  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      title: title,
      children: children,
    );
  }
}
```